# How to fix Azure Data Studio session keeps disconnecting?

Tags: azure-synapse, azure-data-studio

In Azure Data Studio, I have a connection to Synapse Data Warehouse. Recently, I moved to a new Data Warehouse instance but while working in this new instance, I keep getting disconnected issue.

Everything is fine if I open Azure Data Studio and connect to the new database then I can query the Data Warehouse. After a few minutes, The disconnected issue occurs. Reconnect from the same session does not help. I have to close the application, reopen and query again.

Does anyone have the same issue ? How can I fix this ?

Kind regards,

Answer (score 0):

This is a known old issue and unfortunately there is no fix available yet. Similar kind of request to have a default connection for files/folder has already been raised in GitHub [here](https://github.com/microsoft/azuredatastudio/issues/6171).

My suggestion is to keep using SSMS as it works perfectly fine until the fix is available.